# How to combine the contents of multiple columns

Tags: r

When combining information from multiple columns in r, I wonder how to combine duplicate strings while leaving only one.

[image]

thank you.

Comment: What if there are different strings in the rows?

Comment: Please post actual sample data using `dput`

Comment: Rows contain only duplicate strings.

Comment: images of data are **not** data.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following considering the blanks are `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(NA, "s3", NA, NA,"s4"),
                 b=c("s1", NA, "s6", "s7", "s4"),
                 c = c("s1", NA, NA, "s7", NA))

data.frame(a= apply(df,1, function(x)unique(x[!is.na(x)])))

#>   a
#> 1 s1
#> 2 s3
#> 3 s6
#> 4 s7
#> 5 s4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%  
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%  
  drop_na() %>%  
  distinct(value)

# A tibble: 5 × 1
  value
  <chr>
1 s1   
2 s3   
3 s6   
4 s7   
5 s4
```

Comment: thank you!
If all columns a,b,c are "na", can the code you mentioned be executed while maintaining the row as "na"?